# How do I set the email FROM address for a scheduled report?

Tags: email, reporting, scheduled

I have several scheduled reports and dashboards set up to be emailed to management and others. All the emails come from my email address (I am the running user as the admin - everyone may see the data in the reports). I would like to change the FROM address to be a generic one (eg Salesforce Reports|noreply@ourcompany.com), but I can't see any way to do this? Does it just take the running user's email address always?

Comment: did you try a different running user - say a headless user called `salesforceReports-noreply@ourcompany.com` ?

Comment: That would work yes, but to use a full licence for that is just too high a cost :(

Answer (score 0):

One option albeit at a high subscription cost would be to dedicate a User just for SFDC Automated Actions

```
sfdc-automated-actions@mycompany.com
```

and have the scheduled reports originate from that user.

It was pointed out to me the other day in one of my orgs (of less than 100 seats) that 12% of the active users were headless users associated to integrations and other automated actions (Email2Case, Analytic Snapshots, etc.)

That said, there is a huge advantage to using these generic, headless users as they don't stop working when the otherwise with-head user leaves the company and their seat is deactivated. The ensuing panic as stuff stops working (dashboards, analytic snapshots, E2C, marketing automation, weekly export) is well worth the annual subscription cost.